# Python Django ImportError: cannot import name 'Required' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Django version is **3.2.9**.

Python version is **3.10.0**.

And typing_extensions **3.10.0.2**

I'm new to coding, python, etc., and can't figure out what is the problem. Following django tutorial I created an app and ran the server successfully, but a day later, when I tried to do that again I faced this problem:

```
File "C:\Users\fused\Desktop\code\py\myproject\myapp\views.py", line 1, in <module>
from typing_extensions import Required
ImportError: cannot import name 'Required' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\fused\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

After trying to run a server with 'python manage.py runserver' this problem appeared, tried reinstalling typing_extensions, checked versions of everything, but nothing solved the problem.

If any additional information is needed, I'll reply with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks like the `from typing_extensions import Required` line is in your code. Why are you trying to import that? `typing_extensions` doesn't define anything called `Required`.

Comment: Idk how the notifications here work and if you will see that, but thank you, I really somehow scrolled a bit down and couldn't see the import line and you made me re-check everything, maybe blindly following tutorials isn't the best way to learn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Support for `Required` and `NotRequired` have been added to `typing_extensions` version **4.0.0** as experimental features.

Everything should work for now like it's stated in [PEP 655](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0655/).

### Old Answer

It seems like `Required` and `NotRequired` aren't implemented yet in `typing_extensions`.

[PEP 655](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0655/#reference-implementation) states:

> The goal is to be able to make the following statement:
>
> *The mypy type checker supports Required and NotRequired. A reference implementation of the runtime component is provided in the typing_extensions module.*

It's just the goal — it isn't the current state. It is neither listed in `typing_extensions`' [README](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions#included-items) nor does it appear in the source code.

I think it is really confusing that vscode's pylance/pyright can resolve `typing_extensions.Required` and `typing_extensions.NotRequired`, even though it isn't implemented in the module.

As a workaround you could try to replace `from typing_extensions import Required` with

```py
try:
    from typing_extensions import Required
except ImportError:
    from typing import Generic, TypeVar

    T = TypeVar("T")

    class Required(Generic[T]):
        pass
```